# Using <p:commandLink> on a cell in a datatable to open a subtable

Tags: jsf-2, datatable, primefaces, commandlink

I basically have a datatable in which one of the columns is clickable. I have done this by using the commandlink from primefaces.

Everywhere people have used this only to navigate, but I want the click to result in opening a sub datatable. Depending on which row I click on in that column the corresponding datatable must appear.

Can this be done using  in primefaces, if so how do I proceed? 
Thanks

Comment: Nothing really, I have made the column clickable by making use of commandLink - <p:column headerText="Train" style="font-size:90%;font-family:Times New Roman, Times, serif;">
<p:commandLink id="test" ajax = "false" value = "#{rail.trainNo}" action="page-b3"style="font-family:Times New Roman, Times, serif;"/></p:column>

Comment: here I have jus linked it to another page, instead I want to open a table in the same page as the original table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally resolved this problem. I basically created one datatable and hid it, depending on the column clicked I used the backing bean to populate the datatable accordingly.
I made the onclick event call a function in the backing bean using the following code:

```
<p:column headerText="Train" style="font-size:90%;font-family:Times New Roman, Times, serif;">
    <p:commandLink onclick="javascript:ShowHide('HiddenDiv');"
        id="tableUpdater" update=":closeButton,:subForm:trainTable" value="#{rail.trainNo}"
        action="#{yardMaster.populateTrainDetails(rail.trainNo)}"
        style="font-family:Times New Roman, Times, serif;">
    </p:commandLink>
</p:column>
```

So basically something like a dynamic datatable.